# How to get the same timezone using powershell?

Tags: powershell, timestamp

I have PS script in the server, then I want to get the timestamp of the server and parse it to a file. When I get the file from the server from other computer and parse the timestamp of my computer, it gives me different time. 
How do I get the same time of server and my computer?

I tried this

```
[Regex]::Replace([System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local.StandardName, '([A-Z])\w+\s*', '$1')
[TimeZoneInfo]::Local
Get-Date -format r
```

and it retutrn this

```
Id                         : UTC
DisplayName                : (UTC) Coordinated Universal Time
StandardName               : Coordinated Universal Time
DaylightName               : Coordinated Universal Time
BaseUtcOffset              : 00:00:00
SupportsDaylightSavingTime : False

Wed, 11 Sep 2019 09:48:09 GMT
```

But my expectation time is this format, I want to use this `(UTC+08:00)`

```
Id                         : Singapore Standard Time
DisplayName                : (UTC+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore
StandardName               : Malay Peninsula Standard Time
DaylightName               : Malay Peninsula Daylight Time
BaseUtcOffset              : 08:00:00
SupportsDaylightSavingTime : False

Wed, 11 Sep 2019 17:48:25 GMT
```

Comment: you are using `hh` which is 12 hours with AM/PM ... you likely want `HH` for the 24 hour format. ///// are you running the timestamp code on both systems at the SAME SECOND? that is the granularity you are using ... so the two actions would need to happen within approximately 1/2 second of each other. ///// what are you trying to achieve that needs to have the exact same timestamp on actions from two different computers?

Comment: I update my question. I use Get-Date. I want to calculate the period of process using New-Timespan. In my server it show this time `09/11/2019 14:30:05` in other computer that running other ps script show this `09/11/2019 06:30:05`

Comment: That could be anything from timezone difference to incorrectly set computer clocks. Please provide more information and a [mcve] of your non-working code.

Comment: ah! you need to set the time on the one that is wrong. that is usually done by telling the system to use one of the time servers ... and windows defaults to one of your DCs [i think] if you have Active Directory on your network. otherwise it uses `time.windows.com`. ///// until you can correct the different times, you will need to get the start/stop time info from ONE system.

Comment: @SBR - that helps greatly, thanks! [*grin*] it looks like `Ansgar Wiechers` has provided a way to handle your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently your server is configured with the timezone UTC rather than the desired/expected SST (UTC+08). If you can't change the server configuration you may want to get all times in UTC. That way they're directly comparable.

```
(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
```

Comment: Thank you your contribution. I tried this
`$Time1 = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId( `
    (Get-Date), 'Singapore Standard Time')`
And It's wroking as what I need.

Comment: @SBR If you [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/248777) an answer, you will help future readers by showing them what worked. To accept an answer, click the large ✓ symbol below the large number to the left of the answer (you'll get 2 reputation points). If you have at least 15 reputation points, you can also up-vote other helpful answers (optionally also the accepted one). If your problem isn't solved yet, provide feedback, or, if you found the solution yourself, [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).